# How to show symmetric product of complex space is homeomorphic to the complex space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose $\def\Sym{\operatorname{Sym}} \def\C{\mathbb{C}} \Sym^n\C$ is the $n$-fold symmetric product space defined by the quotient map $q: \C^n\to \Sym^n\C$. To show $\C^n$ is homeomorphic to $\Sym^n\C$.

My effort:

I want to show: $g: \Sym^n\C \to \C^n$ defined as
$$
g \bigl( [r_0, \dots, r_{n-1}] \bigr) = \prod_{i=0\,}^{n-1}(z-r_i)
$$
is a homeomorphism, where $z$ is a formal variable. (We write element in $\C^n$ in the form of a $n$-th order polynomial in $z$.)

I have shown that $g$ is a continuous bijective by universal property. I know that one can show the inverse of $g$ is continuous. But the proof is rather long. I would like to know if there is a short proof that $g$ is open or closed.

Comment: Please explain what $z$ is.

Comment: $g([r_0,\cdots,r_{n-1}])$ is a complex polynomial with roots $r_i$. How do you regard this as an element of $\mathbb C^n$? That was the intention of my previous comment. I am aware what the answer is, but it is an essential ingredient and it should be explicitly mentioned in your question.

Comment: @PaulFrost, Sorry for the unclarity. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question [Constructing explicit connected path for coefficients of monic polynomials with roots lying in the open left half plane?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2853674) has at first glance nothing to do with your present question, but in my answer you can find a proof that $g$ is a closed map.